# NoClassDefFoundError in Eclipse Dependant Project

Tags: java, servlets

I have a Servlet project which is depend on another eclipse project named Model. I have a User class in Model project. I have added dependency in Servlet project through eclipse build bath. But when I run the Servlet project, I see this exception saying that it didn't find the definition of User class.

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:User`

Comment: At build time your dependent project is not being included in your project.

Comment: Make Model as jar and add it to Servlet classpath it during the run time.

Comment: @DinoTw I don't want to add it as a jar because every time I make changes in Model project, I need to recreate the jar.

Comment: Have you use any other jar in your model ? May be you use a jar in model but not in servlet project

Comment: Agree with @nitinverma. If that's the case, check the jar on the "Order and Export" tab in Model project.